# Putting all items of an array into a Paypal order function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a project in React where i want to put every item of an array into the Paypal order function.
Below if the file. How can i achive that?

```
export default function Cart(): JSX.Element {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState<Cart>([]);

    return <>
        <ShoppingCart onChange={setCart} cart={cart} />
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={{
            "client-id": process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || "",
            currency: Currency.EURO
        }}>
            <PayPalButtons style={{ layout: "horizontal" }}
                createOrder={(_data, actions) => {
                    // TODO: Make this object be build with cart items including every single item
                    return actions.order.create({
                        purchase_units: [
                            {
                                amount: {
                                    currency_code: Currency.EURO,
                                    value: "1.99",
                                },}, ], }); }}
                onApprove={onApprove}
            />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
    </>
}
```

I tried to map every item into an array and put that into the creatyOrder function like this

````
<>
                <PayPalButtons style={{layout: "horizontal"}}
                               createOrder={(_data, actions) => {
                                   const items = cart.map((item) => ({
                                       name: item.name,
                                       quantity: item.quantity.toString(),
                                       unit_amount: {
                                           currency_code: Currency.EURO,
                                           value: item.price.toFixed(2).toString()
                                       },
                                   }));
                                   return actions.order.create({
                                       purchase_units: [
                                           {
                                               items:  items,
                                               amount: {
                                                   currency_code: Currency.EURO,
                                                   value: cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0).toFixed(2).toString(),
                                                   breakdown: {
                                                       item_total: {
                                                           currency_code: Currency.EURO,
                                                           value: "4.98"
                                                       } } },}, ], }); }}
                               onApprove={onApprove}
                />
            </PayPalScriptProvider>
        </>```

But unfortunatly the order windows closes immediately after pressing the button and i cat this error in the console.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEwgK.png)

I really dont know whats the problem here. Does anyone know what the error means or how i can solve this?
Paypal seems to be a bit special when it comes to make own Requests.
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated and should not be used in any new integrations. React-specific documentation may not yet been updated to reflect this, but you can see in the JS/node samples of the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) that these functions are no longer used (and should never be used).

Instead, create and capture PayPal orders from a backend/server **only**, using the v2/checkout/orders API.

I don't know of a current sample that uses React for the front end portion (edit: ah the new one in [this integration builder](https://developer.paypal.com/integration-builder/) might), but [here you can find a robust Typescript sample](https://github.com/paypal-examples/paypal-sdk-server-side-integration) (plain JS frontend) that you can integrate/pair with your existing React code (which uses the official @paypal/react-paypal-js as far as I can see)

Comment: Do you know of any offical statement that these functions are deprecated? Because I found this docu still having these methods: https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/regional/th/checkout/integrate/